# Semaphores make less sense than before I knew how they worked

Tags: c, semaphore

Okay so I went about learning about semaphores on my own, because the class we had did not teach us much at all (it was a non-english speaking teacher's assistant, great use of my 11,500$).

Anyways, I figured out how to use semaphores, and started my work on the sleeping-barber problem.

The barber waits on his pillow for someone to `sem_post` it. The customer waits for the barber to post the "seatbelt" to say that the customer can leave.

Anyways, I went back to the assignment after realising that the semaphores won't be shared between the processes, since they aren't threads. Supplied with the assignment is the description of the functions `semget`, `semop` and `semctl` which have `structs` as arguments and the explanation is very sparse if at all.

These descriptions directly oppose my findings on the rest of the web which use `sem_open` to open a 'file' which is the semaphore.

Anyways - I guess my question is:

What are the 'keys' sent to the `sem*` functions? sometimes it's set to IPC_PRIVATE and sometimes it is used as a descriptor for the semaphore?

I think these resources are making me more confused than they are helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys are used across the whole SysVIPC subsystem, and they're numerical identifiers meant to be derived from pathnames by means of the [ftok(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftok) function.

You can find more details about SysV semaphores in the manpages or at http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html or in the [APUE book](http://www.apuebook.com/).

Comment: Okay - so I think the issue is that I'm confusing SysVIPC semaphores with another type of semaphore - whatever was used before SysVIPC. would that explain my problem?

Comment: SysVIPC semaphores (manipulated with  sem* functions) are older. POSIX semaphores (manipulated with sem_* functions) are newer, simpler, more performant, but also less powerful (no automatic undo operations, no atomic operations on groups of semaphores).  However, unnamed POSIX semaphores (see the sem_init manpage) ARE shareable across multiple processes too -- you just have to use shared memory and marke it as a shared semaphore). It's all in the manpages.

Comment: That paragraph brought a cloud of understandings together into actual useful information - thank you!